# Fastest and easiest way to change controllers' module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-controller

I am developing my first Zend website, and I just finished the Back-office. The problem is that I did not create any module, but now that I have to develop the Front-office I would like to create a different module.

Knowing that I already have about 20 controllers for my back-office, how could I easily change their module to "Administration" ?

Then I would place the front office in a "Public" module and the main engines will be left in the "Default" module.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use `Zend_Application`.

Enable modules in your application.ini:

```
resources.modules =
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory             = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.frontController.controllerDirectory.default = APPLICATION_PATH "/controllers"
```

Create a new file hierarchie for your new "Public" module:

```
library
public
application
    - controllers // class UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
    - views
    - modules
        - frontend
            - controllers // class Frontend_UserController extends Zend_Controller_Action
            - views
```

Back-office:

```
http://server.tld/user/add
```

Frontend / Public:

```
http://server.tld/frontend/user/list
```